# php unique alpha numeric id

Tags: php, hex, unique, identifier

I have seen a few post on this, but nothing that would work entirely for what I'm trying to do. Pretty much I want to generate a new id for clients in this script. What I want to do is add a new entry to my database, get the id, and then multiply by say `A1A1`, or something like that. So it would be like

```
A1A1 - 1st id
A1A2 - 2nd id
A1A3 - 3rd id
```

(so on and so fort).

Anyone got any ideas where I should start with that?

Comment: what is the business need for doing this rather than using a standard auto-increment or uuid?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You can edit the ID with PHP like `$id = 'A1A' . $id;`.

Comment: Do you want it hexadecimal or alphanumeric?

Did you look into BASE64 encoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just increment your string:

```
$id = 'A1A1';

$new_id = ++ $id; // $new_id is now A1A2
```

[**See it on Ideone**](http://www.ideone.com/Z5jJQ)

Comment: Hmm, I didnt think it would be as easy as ++. Thanks alot

Comment: Hmmm, Im trying to make it so I can just retrieve an id (say 5) from my database, and multiply it by 'A1A1', but that doesnt seem to work, I just get zero, any tips?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this would work, but typically generates somewhat sequential hexdecimal numbers based on the current microsecond.

```
uniqid();
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a SQL database, I would highly suggest checking out auto increment. For example, here is [auto-increment for mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Comment: Isnt auto increment only numeric though?

Answer (score 0):

You may split the whole id into alphabets and numerals. Then increment the corresponding numeral and concatenate back. If you have to make record deletion, take care of the re-arranging the sequence.